# Call a variable from a str

Tags: python, pandas, string, variables, call

I have an Excel spreadsheet - that I read via pandas - with some values corresponding to `A + x` ; A being an already defined value and x being an int.
This Excel is a list of subjects with each subject having a different value for A and B.

I technically found a solution, **but would like to know if there are alternative solutions to what I did**.
The Excel file being massive, **I'd like a solution that doesn't require to write hundreds of lines**.

| ID | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 5 | A+2 |
| 02 | 8 | A+4 |

**Consequently, something like "A + 2" will be listed as str in the pandas DataFrame I get from `pd.read_excel`.**

What I want is to make a DataFrame of, let's say, 10 entries with each entry being either ID 01 or ID 02 randomly selected.

Let's say I select the first line, with A = 5 defined before reading B.
**I'd like to get B = 7 by reading the corresponding entry in pandas.** This would normally be obtainable via DF.iloc[0,1]. **However, A + 2 being str, I can't.**

I found two potent solutions :

1. Using eval() function before iloc. This worked. However, eval() being what it is, I threw this alternative away.
2. Using locals() and a function like the following one:

```
def numeric(equation):
   A = DF.iloc[0,0]
   if '+' in equation:
      x = equation.split('+')
      y = locals()[x[0]]+int(x[1])
      return y
```

Then using `numeric(DF.iloc[0,1])`.

Comment: What's wrong with the second solution using `locals()`?

Comment: "never" use `eval` https://www.udacity.com/blog/2023/03/pythons-eval-the-most-powerful-function-you-should-never-use.html

Comment: @RyanZhang The second solution works like a charm for what I want the code to do. I'm mainly curious of potential alternatives.

Comment: So is every value in column B equal to a string that starts with A, followed by +, then an integer? If so, have you considered stripping off the A and converting the column to numeric, then adding the A column?

Answer (score 0):

If the values of `A` in column `B` are values from column `A`, then you can split the rows into lists using the '+' separator and take the last elements.
Converts the type of columns `A, C` to the 'int64' type.
And then perform the operation of adding the values of both columns, overwriting column `C`.

Or write only the values for addition in column B and perform the addition operation A + B.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['01', '02'], 'A': [5, 8], 'B': ['A+2', 'A+4']})
df['C'] = df['B'].str.split('+').str[1]

df = df.astype({'A': 'int64', 'C': 'int64'})

df['C'] = df['A'] + df['C']
```